# DASH .mpd from mp4box is not playing in Dash.js player

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, media-source

I have Generated a .mpd file using MP4Box and used Dash.js player to play the generated but it is not playing.But if I create a player using details provided in the link (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn551368(v=vs.85).aspx) it is playing. I have followed details exactly given in the above mentioned link and it works fine. But when I use the .mpd in a dash.js player it is not working.

Kindly help me out to resolve this issue.

```
<MPD type="static" xmlns="urn:mpeg:DASH:schema:MPD:2011" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:full:2011" minBufferTime="PT1.5S" mediaPresentationDuration="PT0H1M0.29S">
 <ProgramInformation moreInformationURL="http://gpac.sourceforge.net">
  <Title>Media Presentation Description for file Recorded_gopi.mp4 generated with GPAC </Title>
 </ProgramInformation>
 <Period start="PT0S" duration="PT0H1M0.29S">
  <AdaptationSet>
   <ContentComponent id="1" contentType="video"/>
   <ContentComponent id="2" contentType="audio" lang="und"/>
   <Representation id="1" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.640028,mp4a.40.02" width="1280" height="1024" sampleRate="44100" numChannels="2" lang="und" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="317599">
    <BaseURL>Recorded_gopi_dash.mp4</BaseURL>
    <SegmentList timescale="1000" duration="13915">
     <Initialization range="0-1264"/>
     <SegmentURL mediaRange="1265-512125" indexRange="1265-1465"/>
     <SegmentURL mediaRange="512126-774261" indexRange="512126-512254"/>
     <SegmentURL mediaRange="774262-1165553" indexRange="774262-774390"/>
     <SegmentURL mediaRange="1165554-1484521" indexRange="1165554-1165682"/>
     <SegmentURL mediaRange="1484522-1819145" indexRange="1484522-1484626"/>
     <SegmentURL mediaRange="1819146-2122548" indexRange="1819146-1819310"/>
     <SegmentURL mediaRange="2122549-2375382" indexRange="2122577-2122705"/>
    </SegmentList>
   </Representation>
  </AdaptationSet>
 </Period>
</MPD>
```

Kindly help me out to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you resolved this? Do you mind sharing the code and browser console output. I am having the same issue with dash.js.

Answer (score 2):

I've been facing the same issue few hours and just got clue to resolve the problem.

By removing lines saying as follows, it works very well to me.

```
<ContentComponent id="1" contentType="video" />
<ContentComponent id="2" contentType="audio" />
```

MPD Validator say it's valid whether the lines exist or not. I have no idea why dash.js can't handle properly. Is there any options of MP4Box not to include those lines?

Comment: Removing these lines solved my issue as well. Some tutorials I've seen do suggest having separate video and audio streams segmented. It seems as if those ContentComponent ought to only be present if the video segements aren't muxed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove lines `<ContentComponent ../>`.

It works for me.